# getAccessTokenSilently won't get me a token

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I'm trying to save my token in localstorage, using auth0 onRerirectCallback

```js
  const onRedirectCallback = async (appState) => {
    try {
      const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
      localStorage.setItem('token', token);
      window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, appState?.returnTo || window.location.pathname);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

    <Auth0Provider
      domain={domain}
      clientId={clientId}
      redirectUri={window.location.origin}
      onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
    >
      {children}
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
```

The functions is called, but I don't get a token. What am I doing wrong ?